# How to find the javascript that's making a request to a web page (in my local dev site)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I have a weird bug where something in the depths of our site javascript is causing a bad url to be loaded from the site.  How can I try to work out where in the code this is happening?  I'm using Chrome, and i'm hoping something in the devtools can do this, but I can't figure it out.

This is in my local development version of the website.  There is no javascript error, so no stack trace.  Something in the JS stack is firing off a GET to the back end, and I want to find out where in the code it's being sent from.

Comment: Press F12. If there is a console.error, click on the link to the line and investigate from there. Otherwise run the debugger. You can aslo search usign ctrl-f when the source tab is open

Comment: Hi - there isn't a console error.  It's just an unwanted url being sent to the server.  I don't know what I would search for with ctrl-f.  I will try the debugger though, thanks.

Comment: Also look in your .htaccess, that is where the scammer often redirect requests if that is what is happening

Comment: It's not a scammer.  This is happening in my local development version of the website, too.  A GET request is being sent to my local server, by javascript, and I can't work out where in the JS it's coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the "Network" tab of the developer tools. The column names are Name, Status, Type, Initiator, Size, Time and Waterfall. Initiator tells you the file and the line.

[image]

Comment: That worked - i feel like a bit of a doofus now, but thanks.  Found the problem request, looked at the stack trace, about 10 lines down, there it was. doh.

Comment: Your mention of the stack-trace brings up an important point for future readers of this thread. If a library is used, such as jQuery, the requests will all come from the same file and line, you'll need to trace through the call stack to determine where the library function was called in order to perform the same task. Glad you've solved it.

Comment: Yes, this is the case with the back end as well - the first 20 lines will usually refer to code libraries which I assume are not to blame.  I always look down till I find code written by us :)